# Error: Misplace Else

Tags: c

I tried to print the largest number in the array but there's an error showing misplaced else. I tried putting brackets around but there's still an error in it. I don't have an idea why there is a misplaced else error. Please help : >.<

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
  int lar, yem;
  clrscr();
  int aray[10];
  for (yem = 0; yem < 10; ++yem)
  {
    printf("Input numbers:");
    scanf("%d", &aray[yem]);
  }

  lar = aray[0];

  for (yem = 1; yem < 10; ++yem)
  {
    if (aray[yem] > lar);
      lar = aray[yem];
    else
      ++yem;

    printf("Biggest: %d\n", lar);
   }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)`.

Comment: @alk: If only...please read [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) where you'll find Microsoft has subverted the rule about `int main()`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon `;` from the `if` statement;

```
if(aray[yem]>lar);
                 ^
                 |  
            Remove this
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(aray[yem]>lar);
                  ^^ get rid of this semi-colon
```

Use of this semi-colon will be equivalent to

```
 if(aray[yem]>lar)
    ;
 lar=aray[yem];

 else //Now this else doesn't have a matching if hence the error
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are terminating an if statement with `;`

```
if(aray[yem]>lar);
                 ^         
                 |
```

Delete the `;` at the end

```
if(aray[yem]>lar)
```